# Python - Function does not return an output if all arguments is not passed and does not evaluate the elif statement

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have a Python function that takes inputs from user and executes a SQL statement:

```
def function_name(team, dept start_date, end_date):
    dwh = conn.cursor() ## DB Connection established
    if (team is None):
        dwh.execute(sql.SQL("""select name,dept from employee where group = (%s) and join_date between (%s) and (%s)"""), (group, start_date, end_date))
    elif (dept is None):
        dwh.execute(sql.SQL("""select name,team from employee where team = (%s) and join_date between (%s) and (%s)"""), (team, start_date, end_date))
    else:
        dwh.execute(sql.SQL("""select name,dept,team from employee where team = (%s) and dept =(%s) and join_date between (%s) and (%s)"""), (team, dept start_date, end_date))
```

When I try the above code, it runs when all inputs are provided by the user. If any of the fields are not provided, it returns an empty output.

**Edit :**

Output returned when I share the below input:

```
function_name("team1", "dept1", "2018-01-01","2018-01-31")
```

However when I enter the below it returns an empty output (it should execute the `elif (dept is None):` portion of the script)

```
function_name("team1", "2018-01-01","2018-01-31")
```

Comment: Maybe share your input lines as well? Might have to do with empty fields being empty strings ('') instead of actual None.

Comment: @romanoww, I have edited my post with the function and inputs I am giving

Comment: Your example doesn't match the described behaviour - with the second function call, it should raise a TypeError "function_name takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)". Please post a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I have edited the initial post where I have provided what inputs I am trying to pass as argument to the function. The first function I tried to pass runs using the else statement whereas the second function I shared should run the 'elif (dept is None):' portion but it doesn't. Hope this makes this clearer. Thanks..

Comment: @scottmartin in the second call, you are passing `"2018-01-01"` as the second positional argument, so this gets bound to the `dept` argument. For `dept` to be `None`, you have to pass it as such, ie `function_name("team1", None,  "2018-01-01","2018-01-31")`. There are better ways using default arguments values in the function definition and named arguments at call time but this would be too long for a comment - and it's already well documented here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions anyway.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thanks for the reply. I am only passing 3 arguments when I try this condition as per the sql command here.     "dwh.execute(sql.SQL("""select name,team from employee where team = (%s) and join_date between (%s) and (%s)"""), (team, start_date, end_date))".. also I am using a web app to get user input and have that passed to the function as arguments..

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, since its a web app (flask web-app), there is no provision to pass in arguments but I am trying to have that built in the SQL itself such that depending on what the user inputs the appropriate SQL is executed.

Comment: Please re-read my comment more carefully, and read the doc I linked to. The fact that you're "only passing 3 arguments" doesn't mean that Python will automagically guess you wanted to pass `None` as the second - that's just not how it works. And the fact that this is in a flask app is irrelevant too, a function is a function, period.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you include your input lines for team and dept.

You're missing a comma after dept, should fix the user-defined function.
Furthermore, function_name input should be as followed:

```
def function_name(team, dept, start_date, end_date):
    if (team is None):
        print ("team is none")
    elif (dept is None):
        print ("dept is none")
    else:
        print("else")
```

`function_name(team='team1', dept='dept1', start_date='2018-01-01', end_date='2018-01-01')` prints else

```
function_name(team='team1', dept=None, start_date='2018-01-01', end_date='2018-01-01')
```

prints dept is none

`function_name(team=None, dept='dept1', start_date='2018-01-01', end_date='2018-01-01')`  prints team is none